# "No space left on device" error when compiling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In Xcode, when I tried to run my app on my device (iPhone), I get "no space left on device". The app was working on iPhone yesterday, but today I got this error.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What do *you* think "no space left on device" means?

Comment: means nonsense to me

Comment: This is a common issue for me, despite having a 32GB phone with almost 10GB free storage. It appears obvious that people are down voting as a result of their own inexperience with the issue, which is a common one for me and several developers I have worked with.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted this much? It's a legitimate question which just happened to me even though I'm testing on a brand new 16GB iPad with just one app installed. Xcode is known for giving meaningless, downright wrong error messages.

Answer (score 15):

There are two common steps to this fairly common issue:

1. Delete the app from your device.
2. command+k which will clean your code and run again.

   OR
3. Close Xcode and reopen, run again.

Ensure you delete the app from your device first. If necessary, turn your phone off and on again, but I have never had to do this after erasing the app from the device and reinstalling.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe need to check storage on your Mac. I have the same problem with `Xcode8.3.2` with 2Gb available of SSD on MacBook, after delete somethings then it worked.

Comment: This is not a device issue?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have issue on Mac or windows emulator and not on actual device than please open the disk on which your project code is and check that disk size and not your primary application disk size, you will need space on that disk too which had your project code, I did this and it just worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when building the app in iOS Simulator. I realized that my Mac's storage was full. So, I freed up some space of about 10 GB, and the rebuild was successful.

Answer (score 1):

please free up the memory of your mac machine and try build it will work.

Comment: Memory != Storage

Answer (score 1):

I checked the storage on both iPhone and Mac, there was a lot available.

Logout and re-login made the problem go away (I didn't delete the app from the iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

1. Do Product -> clean. Then delete everything from DerivedData folder and empty trash.
2. To restore some bulk space back, delete some of the simulators and
   build archives that you don't need..

Goto Xcode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Right click and delete some simulators that you won't need for testing..

Also Xcode -> Window -> Organizer. Tap archives and select projects from drop down and remove all archives of builds that you won't need anymore.  Usually you won't need them because you would have already generated ipa from them and would many GBs of space and this issue will be solved.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently seeing this error message ("No space left on device") when creating named semaphores using sem_open(). (A Unix function call) The error message text is returned by a function called errno(), the result of which I write to the console when sem_open fails.

It sounds to me like some code you are using is attempting to create a semaphore and getting this error. It's my understanding that this happens when you create too many named semaphores without freeing them (They persist between runs of your program.) You will probably solve the problem temporarily by rebooting your phone.

The same message may well be displayed by other system functions, not just sem_open. You might try setting a symbolic breakpoint on errno() and seeing if you can find the code that is generating the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check you hard disk, if its full then delete some unwanted data build and run. It worked for me.